# How I can config logger file in Fastify which created from fastifify cli

Tags: fastify

I generated fastify project from fastify cli then I really want to use the logger system and write it into the file

The code below is the way I try but when I send the request it does not write any log file yet and the system does not create any file also.

```js
import { join } from 'path';
import AutoLoad, {AutoloadPluginOptions} from 'fastify-autoload';
import { FastifyLoggerOptions, FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify';

export type AppOptions = {
  // Place your custom options for app below here.
} & Partial<AutoloadPluginOptions> & Partial<FastifyLoggerOptions>;

const app: FastifyPluginAsync<AppOptions> = async (
    fastify,
    opts
): Promise<void> => {
  // Place here your custom code!
  opts.level = 'info'
  opts.file = 'logger'
  fastify.log.info('Test log')
  // Do not touch the following lines

  // This loads all plugins defined in plugins
  // those should be support plugins that are reused
  // through your application
  void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: join(__dirname, 'plugins'),
    options: opts
  })

  // This loads all plugins defined in routes
  // define your routes in one of these
  void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: join(__dirname, 'routes'),
    options: opts
  })

};

export default app;
export { app }
```

the opts.file is the place I put the file path to write all the log of the request.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy the app on production you need a `server.js` file that you invoke with node. Below is the file that you can place next to `app.ts` which instantiates a Fastify app instance and configure logging for you.

```js
 'use strict'
    
    // Read the .env file.
    require('dotenv').config()
    
    // Require the framework
    const Fastify = require('fastify')
    
    // Require library to exit fastify process, gracefully (if possible)
    const closeWithGrace = require('close-with-grace')
    
    // Instantiate Fastify with some config
    const app = Fastify({
      logger: { 
        level: 'info', 
        file: process.env.LOG_FILE  || './app.log'
      }
    })
    
    // Register your application as a normal plugin.
    const appService = require('../dist/app.js')
    app.register(appService)
    
    
    // delay is the number of milliseconds for the graceful close to finish
    const closeListeners = closeWithGrace({ delay: 500 }, async function ({ signal, err, manual }) {
        if (err) {
          app.log.error(err)
        }
        await app.close()
      })
      
      app.addHook('onClose', (instance, done) => {
        closeListeners.uninstall()
        done()
      })
      
      // Start listening.
      app.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 3000, host: '0.0.0.0' }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          app.log.error(err)
          process.exit(1)
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my app.ts file, you can config logger options in the options scope and append -o in your fastify-cli command.

1. config your logger options in app.ts, pay attention to the `// Pass --options via CLI arguments in command to enable these options.` comment part.

```
import * as path from 'path';
import AutoLoad, { AutoloadPluginOptions } from '@fastify/autoload';
import { FastifyPluginAsync, FastifyServerOptions } from 'fastify';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)


export interface AppOptions extends FastifyServerOptions, Partial<AutoloadPluginOptions> {
    // Place your custom options for app below here.
}

// Pass --options via CLI arguments in command to enable these options.
const options: AppOptions = {
    logger: {
        level: 'info',
        customLevels: {
            test: 99
        }
    }
}

const app: FastifyPluginAsync<AppOptions> = async (
    fastify,
    opts
): Promise<void> => {
    // Place here your custom code!

    // Do not touch the following lines

    // This loads all plugins defined in plugins
    // those should be support plugins that are reused
    // through your application
    void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
        dir: path.join(__dirname, 'plugins'),
        options: opts,
        forceESM: true
    })

    // This loads all plugins defined in routes
    // define your routes in one of these
    void fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
        dir: path.join(__dirname, 'routes'),
        options: opts,
        forceESM: true
    })

};

export default app;
export { app, options }
```

2. append `-o` flag in your fastify-cli command, eg. `fastify start -o -P app.js`